# Popup adjust volume

Tags: ios

I wrote an application using AVAudioPlayer to play audio. After the app islaunched, I press 2 buttons on left side of iPhone to adjust volume, a pop-up appears 
[image: Ringer Image]

This is the code I have implemented

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    BOOL success = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
    NSError *activationError = nil;
    success = [audioSession setActive:YES error:&activationError];
```

I can't see a popup appear when I press the button on left side of iPhone to adjust volume. Why doesn't it appear?

How do I show a popup to adjust volume while playing audio?

Answer (score 0):

To let the user adjust / see the volume from interface within your app, use an MPVolumeView.

Comment: I used MPVolumeView to adjust volume, but at view I implement MPVolumeView I can't see volume popup. Why?

Comment: Because the user isn't pressing the buttons on the side of the device. That is what makes the popup appear. You can't make it appear. You could make something that _looks_ like it if you really want to, but _your_ app's interface for adjusting / seeing the volume, as I said, is the MPVolumeView.

Comment: Sorry @matt, I didn't have a clear question. At view I used MPVolumeView, I pressed 2 buttons on left side of iphone to adjust volume, I don't see the popup, I only see the value of MPVolumeView change.